React Native and Kotlin always having to run ./gradlew clean
Whenever I make changes to my kotlin file, I have run ./gradlew clean. And restart my build, with npx react-native run-andorid. Is there a way of making changes to my kotlin file without having to run ./gradlew clean after every kotlin change?
